# Liferay: error opening service.xml

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet, liferay-ide

I am using liferay for a project. I tried creating service.xml using an option NEW LIFERAY SERVICE BUILDER. But I got the below error whenever I tried opening the service.xml.

```
Error
Tue Jul 15 12:52:10 IST 2014
Plug-in "com.liferay.ide.eclipse.service.ui" was unable to instantiate class "com.liferay.ide.eclipse.service.ui.ServiceBuilderEditor".

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "com.liferay.ide.eclipse.service.ui" was unable to instantiate class "com.liferay.ide.eclipse.service.ui.ServiceBuilderEditor".
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:274)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:318)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:266)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
 ... (omitted large parts of stacktrace) ...
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/liferay/ide/eclipse/service/ui/ServiceBuilderEditor, method: createDiagramPages signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
 ... 90 more.
```

My liferay sdk is 6.2, installed liferay version 6.2 in eclipse and  Liferay v6.1 community edition server bundled with Tomcat 7. Please anyone tell me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your eclipse plugins (that make up Liferay IDE) are out of sync. Please update them and check again. This is not happening on the Liferay side, but rather on the Eclipse/Liferay-IDE side.

Comment: I opened it with XML editor and it opened.Thanks @OlafKock

Comment: That's a workaround, not a fix. However, glad that you can keep on working this way. If you ever want to solve the underlying problem (and use the service.xml editor): update

Answer (score 0):

God my silly mistake. I tried opening with XML editor and it opened.